# Как заставить браузер ждать загрузку шрифта? (html/css)

Tags: css3, html5

При загрузке страницы весь текст отображается при помощи стандартных средств (шрифтов). Затем, когда загрузка завершается, все назначенные шрифты подхватываются и резко меняются на странице. Вопрос: как заставить браузер ждать загрузку шрифта? (Не отображать страницу до тех пор, пока шрифты не будут загружены)

Comment: можно лоадер сверху поместить и пока не загрузятся шрифты до тех пор не давать возможность что-то делать на странице

Comment: На [этой](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onload) странице всё есть, включая то, как отображать контент после полной загрузки, а до того чтоб проигрывалась анимация (написано в комментариях)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно к бэку обратиться на самом деле.
Или плагины поискать, чтобы пока сайт не прогрузился, пользователь видел картинку загрузки или типа того.
У меня тоже есть небольшое мигание у шрифтов (видно как они меняются) при загрузке страницы, но это случается только когда я работаю на локальном компьютере, когда заливаю на сервер и работаю там, такого уже нет.
Попробуйте залить на сервер и проверить